# Get all uploaded files

Tags: php

I'm uploading several files and I need to process all of them. But they have "unknown" names back in the form and simple foreach is not working.

```
<input type="file" name="somethingIDontKnow">
<input type="file" name="somethingIDontKnowAgain">
...
```

I need to know the name parameters of inputs. Can I get them somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` parameter to `<form>` so I didn't get any files. It's ok now.